# values from a foreach loop in a function into an array

Tags: arrays, powershell, foreach

I have a function that replaces PackageID in a SCCM task sequence, I would like to capture all those package IDs into a variable, so I would be able to create a report based on that.

The problem is that I already have a `foreach` loop doing the work, and I can't figure out how to not overwrite the values.

`$Driver.PackageID` comes from a `foreach` loop based on `$Drivers`, which contains

[image]

If I run the code I get this as I have `Write-Output` defined:

[image]

**Updated code:**

```
function Set-Drivers{

    foreach ($Driver in $Drivers) {

    Write-Output "Driver Name: $($Driver.Name)"
    Write-Output "DriverPackageID: $($Driver.PackageID)"
    }
}


$array = @()
$array = Set-Drivers
$hash = [ordered]@{

'DriverName'           = $Driver.Name
'DriverID'           = $Driver.PackageID
}

$array += New-Object -Typename PSObject -Property $hash
```

Can someone explain, why I only get the first result in my `$array`? I can see the values are being overwritten if I run it in debug mode.

Comment: you are setting the array to blank in EVERY LOOP. [*grin*]  this `$global:array = @()` needs to be _outside_ your `foreach`.

Comment: What Lee said. Also, do not modify global variables in a function or append to an array in a loop. What you want to do is simply output the objects in the loop (write your status output to the host or the verbose stream instead of the default stream), and then run `$array = Set-Drivers` in the global scope.

Comment: Still only get one result, do you have a suggestion how else it could be done ?

Comment: @BenDK - **_please_** post your _current_ code since your comment doesn't tell us anything about what may be going wrong ... [*grin*]

Comment: @Lee_Dailey updated the main post with the new code

Comment: @BenDK - great! thanks ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function doesn't return anything. It only writes lines to the console. Then after the function is finished, you create a single object and add that to your array.

Try something like

```
function Set-Drivers{
    $result = foreach ($Driver in $Drivers) {
        [PsCustomObject]@{
            'DriverName'  = $Driver.Name
            'DriverID'    = $Driver.PackageID
        }
    }
    # output the result 
    # the comma wraps the result in a single element array, even if it has only one element.
    # PowerShell 'flattens' that upon return from the function, leaving the actual resulting array.
   ,$result
}

$array = Set-Drivers

# show what you've got
$array
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not iterating over the results, but instead only using one of them. This what you intended.

```
$array = $drivers | foreach { 
  [ordered]@{
    DriverName = $_.Name
    DriverID   = $_.PackageID
  }
}
```